# Add model description when registering model after hyperdrive successful run

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have successfully trained a model on Azure Machine Learning Service using Hyperdrive that has now yielded a hyperdrive run instance

```
hyperdrive_run = exp.submit(config=hypertune_config)
hyperdrive_run
best_run = hyperdrive_run.get_best_run_by_primary_metric()
```

As a next step, I would like to register a model while adding a description to the model.:

```
pumps_rf = best_run.register_model(model_name='pumps_rf', model_path='outputs/rf.pkl')
```

There is a `description` column in the Models section of my AML Workspace on Azure portal but the `register_model` method does not seem to have a `description` flag. So how do I go about adding a description to the model so I see it in Azure Portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question :).

Looking at the current version of the API, it doesn't look like you can add the description using `Run.register_model`, as confirmed [by the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run.run?view=azure-ml-py#register-model-model-name--model-path-none--tags-none--properties-none----kwargs-).

You can go around this however by registering the model using the `Model.register` method which, fortunately, includes an argument for `description` as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#register-workspace--model-path--model-name--tags-none--properties-none--description-none-). In your case, you also need to [download the files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run(class)?view=azure-ml-py#download-file-name--output-file-path-none-) first.

In short, use something like:

```python
best_run.download_file('outputs/rf.pkl', output_file_path='./rf.pkl')

Model.register(workspace=ws, model_path='./rf.pkl', model_name="pumps_rf", description="There are many models like it, but this one is mine.")
```

Comment: Vlad, thanks for responding. Trying: `pumps_rf = Model.register(workspace=ws, model_path='outputs/rf.pkl', model_name="pumps_rf", description="test")` yields error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'outputs/rf.pkl'`. I tried `pumps_rf = Model(workspace=ws, id=best_run.id)` to see if I can register by the run id of the best hyperdrive run but this errors out too: `WebserviceException: ModelNotFound: Model with ID pumps-exp1_1550672326863_1 not found in provided workspace` any ideas?

Comment: Right, it looks like you'll need to download the model first (a bit convoluted, I know). I've updated the answer with info on how to use download_file - haven't tried it myself though, so there may be some kinks.

Comment: Thanks again. This works but hopefully Microsoft will add a `description` flag in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found this same issue, I resolved with this solution: [How to register model from the Azure ML Pipeline Script step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58933565/how-to-register-model-from-the-azure-ml-pipeline-script-step/59694422#59694422)

Which was strange as it is not listed in any official examples.