# How to register model from the Azure ML Pipeline Script step

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I am running the `pipeline.submit()` in AzureML, which has a `PythonScriptStep`.
Inside this step, I download a model from tensorflow-hub, retrain it and save it as a `.zip`, and finally, I would like to register it in the Azure ML.
But as inside the script I do not have a workspace, `Model.register()` is not the case.
So I am trying to use `Run.register_model()` method as below:

```
os.replace(os.path.join('.', archive_name + '.zip'), 
           os.path.join('.', 'outputs', archive_name + '.zip'))

print(os.listdir('./outputs'))
print('========================')

run_context = Run.get_context()
finetuning_model = run_context.register_model(model_name='finetuning_similarity_model',
                                              model_path=os.path.join(archive_name+'.zip'),
                                              tags={},
                                              description="Finetuning Similarity model")
```

But then I have got an error:

> ErrorResponse 
>   {
>       "error": {
>           "message": "Could not locate the provided model_path retrained.zip in the set of files uploaded to the run:

despite I have the retrained `.zip` in the `./outputs` dir as we can see from the log:

```
['retrained.zip']
========================
```

I guess that I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to fix the same issue ([`ModelPathNotFoundException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.exceptions.modelpathnotfoundexception?view=azure-ml-py)) by explicitly uploading the model into the run history record before trying to register the model:

```
run.upload_file("outputs/my_model.pickle", "outputs/my_model.pickle")
```

Which I found surprising because this wasn't mentioned in many of the official examples and according to the `upload_file()` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run.run?view=azure-ml-py#upload-file-name--path-or-stream-):

> Runs automatically capture file in the specified output directory, which defaults to "./outputs" for most run types. Use upload_file only when additional files need to be uploaded or an output directory is not specified.

Comment: In my case, the model path is passed as PipelineData from a previous step. So I had to use the PipelineData path as the "path_or_stream" parameter in run.upload_file(). Then I defined another path in the outputs/ directory as the "name" parameter. This uploads the model to the current run context. Then I used this path as the "model_path" parameter in run.register_model(). Took a while to figure out this one... :|

Comment: This worked for me. What is surprising though is , if I dump a csv file in the outputs folder, it becomes immediately available for registering as dataset, but surprisingly it does't work the same way for model registration. An explicit upload_file needs to be called. And the NOTE in the upload_file documentation is very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there a part of the path missing here:

> model_path=os.path.join(archive_name+'.zip')

Should the path include the outputs subfolder, like this?

> model_path=os.path.join("./outputs",archive_name+'.zip')

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works, but it is strange, because in the Docs model path should be relative to /outputs dir:
_model_path_
_The relative cloud path to model from outputs/ dir. When not specified (None), model_name is used as the path._

Comment: It would appears that the documents are wrong. According to [this](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/583#issuecomment-574731454) github comment "We clarified the description for model_path parameter. It's not relative to the outputs/ directory, which is a commonly used in examples, but rather relative to root of the run's file structure. When in doubt, use run.get_files() to see the files (with paths) created by the run."

Comment: Correct, the documentation is in process of being updated to: 'The relative cloud path to the model, for example, "outputs/modelname". When not specified (None), model_name is used as the path.'